# Is editing another user's answer like this a reasonable interpretation of the "add updates as the post ages" guideline?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help, specific-edit

I noticed a [major edit to a 13-year-old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/778290/revisions) today, in which the editor (who is not the original author) changed it from a short history-based explainer into a much broader treatment advocating for a specific design philosophy, which was not evident anywhere in the original answer. (Compare [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/778290/2) versus [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/778290/4).)

The question I'm asking here has certainly been [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/should-accepted-answers-on-old-questions-be-edited-to-reflect-the-best-answer) [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338481/does-this-edit-change-the-meaning-of-the-answer), [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311574/is-this-major-edit-justified) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313761/clarification-regarding-editing-answers-of-other-users). It's my opinion that a good test is found in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311574/is-this-major-edit-justified):

> As a rule of thumb, ask yourself: **will the author agree with the edit?**
>
> Unless the answer is a resounding **Yes**, then the edit is questionable.

I have no reason to believe, and some reason to doubt, that the edit I linked above would pass this test, which is what made it look to me like a questionable edit. I mentioned as much to the editor in a comment (though I didn't cite this test, and I shouldn't have used as inflammatory a descriptor as "basically vandalism;" *mea culpa*) and suggested adding the content as a new answer instead, and took no other action.

The editor responded with these admittedly intriguing points:

> According to this site's guides and/or rules, bigger edits and/or improvements are preferred vs smaller. Actually you are the first to complain in my last 500+ edits.
>
> Also, 13 years? means needs an update worth 13 years of edits.

Reconsidering whether I've been wrong in my interpretation of what is "too much" for an edit, I checked the rules in [this Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), and found these guidelines [emphasis mine]:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

This *generally aligns* with the editor's response to me in the comments, and it could be argued that the edit, though major, is a valid application of the bolded text above. So, for this question, I'm inclined to let the original author, who appears to still be active on the site, be the ultimate arbiter, and roll back if they so choose.

In the general case, though, what's the guidance?

- Is it encouraged to take the liberty of adding information that takes an old answer in a new direction, if that's determined to be a useful direction?
- If so, how do you choose which answer (in the example looked at here, the info could have been added to most of the other answers without any problem), or should you add it to all of them?
- Is all of this moot because the original question was opinion-based and unsuitable for the site to begin with, and the answers to the questions I'm asking really only apply to opinion-based answers?

Comment: "And am I allowed to ask this many questions in one post?" - on meta, generally yes, as long as they're at least about the same situation.

Comment: Since you posted this answer there was a short rollback war and now the answer is locked. I see two distinct substantial edits, one is much more extensive than the last edit by that editor before rollback. I suppose we can answer your questions as it applies to both edits, but if you want to reference only one particular edit please take a look at the revision history and pick the edit.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this an *update*, which to me implies getting into shape what is already there. Rather this adds some entirely new content, which also seems rather tangential for the question.

Comment: There are [some very useful, comprehensive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-i-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript/221297#221297) which [*started out as a single line of code*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/221297/revisions) (!) and were slowly assembled over the years by editors that were not the original author. Edits are an awesome thing. In this case, though, I think the utility is minimal and the change is drastic enough to warrant a new answer.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That example is wild! From 2014 onward the answer looks for all the world like a "community wiki" but the author's name is still on it. Is that the norm, or an outlier because of the extreme popularity of the question? Editing to add: I feel like the site has since added functionality that would better incentivize each of those "here's a better way to get a timestamp in javascript" edits to be new answers instead, BUT either way, those edits are very clearly "updates as the post ages," whereas, as MisterMiyagi commented, it's not so clear in the case of the edit I'm asking about.

Comment: @user513951 It happens sometimes on very popular questions/answers. Here's [another "Frankenstein" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/365102) vs [[original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/394814/3)] from the top 10 python questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this edit a reasonable interpretation of "add updates as the post ages"?

**Absolutely not.**

The question posed is ultimately a very narrow one, and answers to it should thus be equivalently focused. The original answer conformed to this: it was short, sweet, and to the point. (I would argue that it would have been even better if it had consisted only of its first sentence.)

The edits made to it afterwards completely removed that focus. Now instead of being an answer to the question as asked, it was an answer plus some other bits and bobs that are only tangentially relevant to what was asked and almost certainly won't be relevant to people looking for the direct answer to the question. In other words, it's gone from being a simple-but-effective answer to a bloated piece of waffle that most people aren't going to read past the first sentence anyway.

The justification made by that editor for their hack job is pathetic. The question is ultimately a historical one, this particular piece of history is known and won't change, so there is no justification to change the answer because it's "out of date". Their argument to authority about the number of edits they've made doesn't fly with me either... based on their behaviour on this answer, I don't see 500+ good edits, I see 500+ edits that need to be investigated and possibly rolled back. "It takes 20 years to build a reputation and 5 minutes to ruin it"...

Thank you for noticing and helping to keep this site clean.

Comment: I was with you all the way until you vandalized your otherwise excellent answer with that silly final sentence.

Comment: @skomisa I don't understand your comment. Which sentence do you mean, and what's wrong with it? "It takes 20 years..." or "Thank you for noticing..."?

Comment: @user513951 I believe they refer to the vandalism part of the answer ("_Thank you for noticing and helping to prevent this vandalism._").

Comment: "I see 500+ edits that need to be investigated and possibly rolled back." To be honest, this was also my initial reaction to that comment ("_you are the first to complain in my last 500+ edits_") but rather than set off on that crusade I decided it would be prudent to come here and see what the experts thought. By the way, I immediately recognized your name as the author of the 2015 `editing-help` question I linked, so your opinion is of special interest to me.

Comment: @user513951 I am referring to _"prevent this vandalism"_ in the final sentence. This answer did a fine job of explaining why the edits were unwarranted, but nothing to explain why the edits were _"vandalism"_. Whatever your opinion of the edits mentioned in the OP, there is no basis for claiming they were vandalism. They were made in good faith (albeit mistakenly in my opinion), and were obviously not ["willful or malicious destruction or defacement"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vandalism).

Comment: @skomisa That's a good explanation, and I appreciate it. As I mention in my original post, I immediately regretted saying (in a comment that is now deleted, presumably by a mod in the process of cleaning up), that because it was such an extensive departure from the original answer, the edit amounted to "basically vandalism." I agree with you that the edits were made in good faith, and I should not have introduced the notion of vandalism into the discourse in the first place.

Comment: @skomisa You're missing the forest for the trees with that pedantry. When an answer is edited and the end result is a worse answer, whether the editor intended to improve the answer or damage it is irrelevant; [*the answer is still worse*](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2020/jun/24/monkey-christ-worst-art-repairs-of-all-time).

Comment: Re _"When an answer is edited and the end result is a worse answer, whether the editor intended to improve the answer or damage it is irrelevant"_, not so. It is highly relevant if you are going to accuse the person making the edits of vandalism. Words have meanings, and vandalism requires **wilful destruction**, so if you are going to gratuitously accuse the user of vandalism, have the decency to explain why. Are you seriously claiming the edits were made to deliberately make the answer worse? If not, you should have the decency to withdraw your accusation.

Comment: @skomisa Fair, I've removed the phrase "vandalism".